# Dataset ou DataReader? - Programação em C# .NET

Tags: c#, dataset

Projetos orientados a dados são muito usados em aplicações desktop, estou com um projeto de biblioteca em que salva os registros de membros. Estou a utilizar o método da **Aplicação em 3 camadas**, consiste em muita eficiência e mantém o código limpo. No DataSet: desejo uma ambiguidade da **chave** do usuário tanto no mesmo, como na base. Segue um exemplo do código no qual estou a utilizar:

```
public int InsertMembro(Membro m)
    {
        string sexo;
        int key;

        if (m.MemberSexo == MembroSexo.Feminino)
            sexo = "F";
        else
            sexo = "M";
        //Insere na base de dados
        key = (int) usersTBL.MembroINSERT(m.MemberName,
            m.MemberRG, m.MemberEndereço, m.MemberBairro, m.MemberCidade, m.MemberNascimento, m.MemberTelefone,
            m.MemberEscola, sexo);

        //Salva os dados no DataSet
        dataset.Users.AddUsersRow(m.MemberName,
            m.MemberRG, m.MemberEndereço, m.MemberBairro, m.MemberCidade, m.MemberNascimento, m.MemberTelefone,
            m.MemberEscola, sexo);

        return key;
    }
```

Nota-se que o registro é salvo tanto em memória, como na base. Pensei a respeito do método *TableAdapter*.Fill(), mas usar muito esse método não torna a aplicação lenta?

Penso a respeito se o valor da *primary key* vai se alterar se tratando de um mesmo registro. Isso poderia causar vários problemas.

Comment: São objetos com propósitos diferentes. O `DataReader`, por exemplo, não serve para persistência. Em qual aspecto gostaria de compará-los?

Comment: São de propósitos diferentes, mas a dúvida é em relação ao salvamento, pois como viu, chamei dois métodos, um para salvar na base e, o outro para salvar no dataset. Usar o método fill muitas vezes não torna a aplicação lenta?

Comment: Preciso que você coloque esta parte também no corpo da sua pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta reformulada.